# Visual Studio Team Services: Get all workitems using RestSharp and JSON.NET

Tags: json.net, azure-devops, restsharp, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to get all workitems from Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). I've been able to create them from my application but having issues finding all of them. I have been trying to use the wiql but i dont seem to get it to work. Any help or hints are apreciated.

my code:

```
  var Client = new RestClient("https://myvso.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0");
        Client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;


        var query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new QueryModel() {query = "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems" });

        request.AddJsonBody(query);
        var response = Client.Execute(request);
```

The error i keep getting is:

```
"{\"count\":1,\"value\":{\"Message\":\"Error converting value \\\"{\\\"query\\\":\\\"Select [System.Id], From WorkItems\\\"}\\\" to type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Web.Models.Wiql'. Path '', line 1, position 52.\\r\\n\"}}"
```

Can someone give me a tip as to what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

Remove:

```
var query = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new QueryModel() {query = "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems" });
```

Update:

```
request.AddJsonBody(new {query = "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems" });
```